# Why does not appear the swipe button in my .apk program?

Tags: android-studio, button, apk, swipe, swipe-gesture

I am using a swipe button from com.ebanx:swipe-button library in my application.
The swipe button in the emulator works perfectly, but when I compile the program (app-debug.apk) and install the program and start it, the swipe button doesn't appear for some reason.
What could be the reason. I developed the program from Android 8.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is the code: Here the activity_enter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/plejadian"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".EnterActivity"
    tools:visibility="visible">

<com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton
        android:id="@+id/swipe_button"
        android:layout_width="563dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="469dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="501dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="248dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="199dp"
        app:button_background="@drawable/swipe_button_shape"
        app:button_bottom_padding="10dp"
        app:button_image_disabled="@drawable/ic_right_arrow_simple"
        app:button_image_enabled="@drawable/ic_right_arrow_double"
        app:button_left_padding="15dp"
        app:button_right_padding="2dp"
        app:button_top_padding="10dp"
        app:inner_text=">>  KÉRLEK LÉPJ BE  >>"
        app:inner_text_background="@drawable/swipe_inner_text_shape"
        app:inner_text_bottom_padding="28dp"
        app:inner_text_color="#C9DC17"
        app:inner_text_size="25sp"
        app:inner_text_top_padding="28dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here the java:

```
package com.example.firsttutorial;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton;

public class EnterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter);

        SwipeButton swipe_button = findViewById(R.id.swipe_button);
        swipe_button.setOnStateChangeListener(active -> startActivity(new Intent(EnterActivity.this,CompanyIntroActivity.class)));

    }
}
```

Here the drawable library:

swipe_button_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00374E"/>
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

swipe_inner_text_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00374E"/>
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

And here the com.ebanx:swipe-button library -> build.gradle(:app)

```
implementation 'com.ebanx:swipe-button:0.4.0'
```

So that’s it, I would really like to thank everyone for their help.

Regards
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with the ebanx swipe button dependency not being recognized and fixed it by adding  `jcenter()` under `pluginManagement` and `dependencyResolutionManagement` in the settings.gradle file